# The meaning of "plus" (more/anymore)

Tags: sens, négation

I wonder what the meaning of the word ***plus*** is in the following sentence:

> Attendre simplement que la somme de vos rechargements ne dépasse plus 250€.

Right now I understand it like:
"Simply wait for the sum of your reloads not to go past €250"

But I am not sure whether the ***plus*** here says it is "more than €250" or something with the word "anymore" since it is the structure ***ne...plus***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it has the structure "ne...plus" so it means "not...anymore".
So you should translate it as follow :

> Simply wait for the sum of your reloads not to be over 250€ anymore

Answer (score 2):

Your second assumption is the right one: *plus* in that phrase means ***any longer*** or ***anymore***.